# Undefined method after combining queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My models are:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  has_many  :activities
  has_many  :restaurants
end


class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :city
end
```

On the cities index page i want to show the activities and restaurants from all cities based on boolean value in one each loop.

My city controller:

```
def index 
@region = Region.find(params[:region_id])
@cities = @region.cities

@activities = @cities.activities.find_all_by_homepage_city(true)
@restaurants = @city.restaurants.find_all_by_homepage_city(true)
@activities_restaurants = @activities + @restaurants
end
```

View city index page

```
- @activities_restaurants.each do |b|
              %li 
                =link_to b.name, polymorphic_path([@region, @city, b])
```

I get the error message "undefined method `activities'" What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line causes the error:

```
@activities = @cities.activities.find_all_by_homepage_city(true)
```

You cant call @cities.activities, instead do the following:

add has_many through association to Region

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities, :through => :cities
end
```

then you will be able to call:

```
@activities = @region.activities.find_all_by_homepage_city(true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The query works now! But the polymorphic_path not. I got the message...undefined method `region_activity_path'

Comment: You have to update your question to provide more informations: routes, city index page (if updated)

Comment: hi...i made a new question, with more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948485/relationships-through-with-polymorphic-path

Comment: I think I helped you so could you accept this answer for my contribution? :)

Answer (score 0):

Is @city set somewhere else? Not seeing it in the code here.

I would try simplifying your code. If you reduce @activities_restaurants to just @activities or @restaurants, rather than both, does either work?

That'll get you started at least.